# Calculating Squared Euclidean distance

Tags: php, mysql, euclidean-distance

I have an exe which return an array of 16elements.I have to pass this array to Mysql using php to calculate the Euclidean distance.My table in MySQL is in the form.

```
    id |img_id | features_1|features_2|features_3|features_4|features_5|features_6|features_7|...upto features_16
     1   1        0.389       0.4567     0.8981      0.2345
     2   2        0.9878      0.4567     0.56122     0.4532        
     3   3        
     4   4        
     ......................
```

So I have 16 features for each image and now I have 30,000 images that is img_id is upto 30,000. I have to calculate the euclidean distance of the array from exe which is passed through php with the datas in the database and return the img_id of the 6 images whose euclidean distance is minimum. i.e. Suppose I have an array from exe A[0.458,0.234,0.4567,0.2398] I have to compute distance of each img_id with this array i.e for img_id=1 the distance will be ((0.458-0.389)^2+(0.234-0.4567)^2+(0.4567-0.8981)^2+(0.2398-0.2345)^2) and I have to repeat this process for all the 30,000 images and return the 6 img_id who has least distance. What is the efficient and fast way to calculate it?

Comment: By hand.  Your table doesn't seem set up for it.  Is `id` `auto_increment`?  Do do this sort of thing, you really should have one row for each image with the `features` being more descriptive and separate columns.

Comment: Yes the id is auto increment. Will it be easier if I save the features in separate columns than separate rows?

Comment: Yes, in order to do this type of calculation with any sort of accuracy all the features for one image need to be set up with their own column.

Comment: okay I have saved my features as column and have edited the question now how can I calculate the distance in mysql?

Answer (score 3):

Since php is slow you should do this directly in the SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
ORDER BY ABS(f1 - :f1) + ABS(f2 - :f2) + ... DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

Note that I used the absolute norm instead of the euclidian norm which makes no difference if you are not interested in the actual values (because in vector spaces with finite dimension all norms are equivalent). sqlite for eample does not provide the `SQUARE` function and writing `(f1 - :f1) * (f1 - :f1)` all the time is anoying, so I guess this is a nice solution.